# DB2 ROWID in subquery error

Tags: sql, db2

While running the following query:

```
SELECT T.ROWID FROM TABLE1 T WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT T.ROWID FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T2.C21= T.C11) AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 F WHERE T.C11 = F.C31)
```

results in the error

```
SQL0206N  "ROWID" is not valid in the context where it is used.
SQLSTATE=42703
```

while

```
SELECT T.ROWID FROM TABLE1 T WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T2.C21= T.C11) AND EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 F WHERE T.C11 = F.C31)
```

works fine. What is the reason and what should be the remedy?

**Edit:**
I need to uniquely identify a row in the table. The table doesn't have any key fields and I am not allowed to edit the table data. Therefore I have resorted to use ROWID. 
Regarding the comment that it can be done via joins, I may need to use ROWID with other criteria as the following query:

```
 SELECT T.ROWID FROM TABLE1 T WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T2.ROWID= T.ROWID) AND EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE3 F WHERE T.C11 = F.C31).
```

Even in this case, I would not be able to use ROWID for comparison. Am I right?

Comment: Does `SELECT T.ROWID FROM TABLE2 T2 WHERE T2.C21= T.C11` execute?

Comment: The two should be the same, first of all.  And, you probably mean `t2.ROWID` in the subquery.

Comment: @Andrew No it doesn't. But using only the EXISTS clause works.

Comment: "_No it doesn't_" -- it's probably because the `T` alias is not defined in the subquery, only `T2`...

Comment: @mustaccio If that's the case, T.C11 is accessible in the subquery.

Comment: Read documentation about `ROWID`. Then stop using it.

Comment: Agree with mustaccio - DB2's `ROWID` isn't something you should really be using.  What are you wanting to use it for here?  Also, if the tables in the subqueries only have one row per `T.c11`, you change this to using joins...